# Moving a Arc<Future> into Threadpool

Tags: rust, async-await, threadpool

I have a simple example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af2a64330704da2f4b5abb18a15c8505)) where in the first instance I'm using a Box::pin() to move a future into an local executor.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use futures::executor::LocalPool;
use futures::task::SpawnExt;
use std::sync::Arc;

async fn foo(input: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("foo {}", input);
    42 + input
}


fn code() {
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let mut map: BTreeMap<i32, _> = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(1, Box::pin(foo(1)));
    map.insert(2, Box::pin(foo(2)));

    let mut two = map.get_mut(&2).unwrap();
    let mut one = map.get_mut(&1).unwrap();

    let spawner = pool.spawner();
    spawner.spawn(async move { one.await; });
//    println!("one: {} two: {}", one, two);
}


fn code2() {
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let mut map: BTreeMap<i32, _> = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(1, Arc::pin(foo(1)));
    map.insert(2, Arc::pin(foo(2)));

    let mut two = map.get_mut(&2).unwrap();
    let mut one = map.get(&1).unwrap();

    let spawner = pool.spawner();
    let one = Arc::get_mut(&mut one.clone());
    spawner.spawn(async move { one.await; });
//    println!("one: {} two: {}", one, two);
}

fn main() {
    code();
}
```

In function code2() I'm replacing it with Arc, because instead of a localpool I want to utilise a threadpool. (not shown as that is not available in playground). Unfortunately it errors with

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:28
   |
37 |     let one = Arc::get_mut(&mut one.clone()).unwrap();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::sync::Arc`, found struct `std::pin::Pin`
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut std::sync::Arc<_>`
              found type `&mut std::pin::Pin<std::sync::Arc<impl core::future::future::Future>>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What is the appropriate way to move an `Arc`'d and `Pin`'ned future into a threadpool?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a non-problem. It can be done with an Arc as long as there is also a Box::pin as well.

```
   fn thread_pool() {
        use futures::executor::ThreadPool;
        use async_std::sync::Mutex;
        let pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();

        let mut map: BTreeMap<i32, _> = BTreeMap::new();
        let fut =  Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::pin(async {1})));
        map.insert(1,fut);

        let mut one = map.get(&1).unwrap().clone();

        pool.spawn(async move { 
            let mut guard = one.lock().await;
            let x  = (&mut *guard).await;
        });

    }
```

But is probably not necessary and may lead to undefined behaviour. For example once the future has completed the map holds a reference to a dead future which may be accessed. So the correct solution is not to store the future in a map in the first place. Using a `Box::pin` is sufficient

```
fn thread_pool() {
    use futures::executor::ThreadPool;
    let mut pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
    let fut = Box::pin(async {1});

    pool.spawn(async move { 
        let x :i32 = fut.await;
    });
}
```